# CSS Grid items not aligned as one row in Django template with tailwind-css

Tags: css, django, django-templates, tailwind-css

I am new to Django and ran into this issue.
so basically I am making an app where I have to **display rooms** on the main home page.
The rooms are generated dynamically and are stored in the database that are fetched for the home page like this (in the views.py)

```py
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'base/index.html', {'rooms':rooms})
```

then the index.html will display the data in the form of cards using jinja for loop, something like this, *just ignore the classes and all that, they are just dummy images*, here I am using **tailwind-css** for styling

```html
{% for room in rooms %}
<div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 border-4 border-red-400 lg:grid-cols-4 sm:grid-cols-2 gap-10">
    <div class="rounded overflow-hidden border-4 border-red-400 shadow-lg">
        <a href="/room/{{room.id}}">
            <div class="relative">
                <img class="w-full"
                    src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/196667/pexels-photo-196667.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
                    alt="Sunset in the mountains">
                <div
                    class="hover:bg-transparent transition duration-300 absolute bottom-0 top-0 right-0 left-0 bg-gray-900 opacity-25">
                </div>
                <a href="#!">
                    <div
                        class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 bg-indigo-600 px-4 py-2 text-white text-sm hover:bg-white hover:text-indigo-600 transition duration-500 ease-in-out">
                        {{room.id}}
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="!#">
                    <div
                        class="text-sm absolute top-0 right-0 bg-indigo-600 px-4 text-white rounded-full h-16 w-16 flex flex-col items-center justify-center mt-3 mr-3 hover:bg-white hover:text-indigo-600 transition duration-500 ease-in-out">
                        <span class="font-bold">27</span>
                        <small>March</small>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class="px-6 py-4">
            <a href="#"
                class="font-semibold text-lg inline-block hover:text-indigo-600 transition duration-500 ease-in-out">{{room.name}}</a>
            <p class="text-gray-500 text-sm">
                {{room.desc}}
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="px-6 py-4 flex flex-row items-center">
            <span href="#" class="py-1 text-sm font-regular text-gray-900 mr-1 flex flex-row items-center">
                <svg height="13px" width="13px" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512"
                    style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
                    <g>
                        <g>
                            <path d="M256,0C114.837,0,0,114.837,0,256s114.837,256,256,256s256-114.837,256-256S397.163,0,256,0z M277.333,256
      c0,11.797-9.536,21.333-21.333,21.333h-85.333c-11.797,0-21.333-9.536-21.333-21.333s9.536-21.333,21.333-21.333h64v-128
      c0-11.797,9.536-21.333,21.333-21.333s21.333,9.536,21.333,21.333V256z" />
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </svg>
                <span class="ml-1">6 mins ago</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

I am using **tailwindcss** for styling, and the display grid doesn't seem to work with this, I have added **grid-cols-4** for large screens, which means 4 columns of 1 fr so that 4 divs can be placed in 1 line, but only 1 is being placed and rest just goes to different line. (red borders are for troubleshooting)
[image]

In my understanding, the css applied is not able to detect the dynamically generated set of data, and consider only 1 card.

How to fix this and make 3-4 dynamically generated grid items to be in one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a mistake while calling a loop. I don't know how Django works but you should call the loop after the first `div`. So some pseudo-code can be like this

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 border-4  lg:grid-cols-4 sm:grid-cols-2 gap-10">
  <!-- call loop here or use something like "map function" equivalent in django-->
 

  <div class="rounded overflow-hidden border-4 border-red-400 shadow-lg">
    .
    .
    .
  </div>

 <!-- call ends here -->
</div>
```

Below I am adding the tailwindcss code , since I can’t apply loop here so I just copy-paste the 4 cards code repetitively

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 border-4  lg:grid-cols-4 sm:grid-cols-2 gap-10">
  <!-- call loop here or use something like "map function" equivalent in django-->
    <div class="rounded overflow-hidden border-4 border-red-400 shadow-lg">
        <a href="/room/{{room.id}}">
            <div class="relative">
                <img class="w-full"
                    src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/196667/pexels-photo-196667.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
                    alt="Sunset in the mountains">
                <div
                    class="hover:bg-transparent transition duration-300 absolute bottom-0 top-0 right-0 left-0 bg-gray-900 opacity-25">
                </div>
                <a href="#!">
                    <div
                        class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 bg-indigo-600 px-4 py-2 text-white text-sm hover:bg-white hover:text-indigo-600 transition duration-500 ease-in-out">
                        {{room.id}}
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="!#">
                    <div
                        class="text-sm absolute top-0 right-0 bg-indigo-600 px-4 text-white rounded-full h-16 w-16 flex flex-col items-center justify-center mt-3 mr-3 hover:bg-white hover:text-indigo-600 transition duration-500 ease-in-out">
                        <span class="font-bold">27</span>
                        <small>March</small>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class="px-6 py-4">
            <a href="#"
                class="font-semibold text-lg inline-block hover:text-indigo-600 transition duration-500 ease-in-out">{{room.name}}</a>
            <p class="text-gray-500 text-sm">
                {{room.desc}}
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="px-6 py-4 flex flex-row items-center">
            <span href="#" class="py-1 text-sm font-regular text-gray-900 mr-1 flex flex-row items-center">
                <svg height="13px" width="13px" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512"
                    style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
                    <g>
                        <g>
                            <path d="M256,0C114.837,0,0,114.837,0,256s114.837,256,256,256s256-114.837,256-256S397.163,0,256,0z M277.333,256
      c0,11.797-9.536,21.333-21.333,21.333h-85.333c-11.797,0-21.333-9.536-21.333-21.333s9.536-21.333,21.333-21.333h64v-128
      c0-11.797,9.536-21.333,21.333-21.333s21.333,9.536,21.333,21.333V256z" />
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </svg>
                <span class="ml-1">6 mins ago</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rounded overflow-hidden border-4 border-red-400 shadow-lg">
        <a href="/room/{{room.id}}">
            <div class="relative">
                <img class="w-full"
                    src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/196667/pexels-photo-196667.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
                    alt="Sunset in the mountains">
                <div
                    class="hover:bg-transparent transition duration-300 absolute bottom-0 top-0 right-0 left-0 bg-gray-900 opacity-25">
                </div>
                <a href="#!">
                    <div
                        class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 bg-indigo-600 px-4 py-2 text-white text-sm hover:bg-white hover:text-indigo-600 transition duration-500 ease-in-out">
                        {{room.id}}
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="!#">
                    <div
                        class="text-sm absolute top-0 right-0 bg-indigo-600 px-4 text-white rounded-full h-16 w-16 flex flex-col items-center justify-center mt-3 mr-3 hover:bg-white hover:text-indigo-600 transition duration-500 ease-in-out">
                        <span class="font-bold">27</span>
                        <small>March</small>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class="px-6 py-4">
            <a href="#"
                class="font-semibold text-lg inline-block hover:text-indigo-600 transition duration-500 ease-in-out">{{room.name}}</a>
            <p class="text-gray-500 text-sm">
                {{room.desc}}
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="px-6 py-4 flex flex-row items-center">
            <span href="#" class="py-1 text-sm font-regular text-gray-900 mr-1 flex flex-row items-center">
                <svg height="13px" width="13px" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512"
                    style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
                    <g>
                        <g>
                            <path d="M256,0C114.837,0,0,114.837,0,256s114.837,256,256,256s256-114.837,256-256S397.163,0,256,0z M277.333,256
      c0,11.797-9.536,21.333-21.333,21.333h-85.333c-11.797,0-21.333-9.536-21.333-21.333s9.536-21.333,21.333-21.333h64v-128
      c0-11.797,9.536-21.333,21.333-21.333s21.333,9.536,21.333,21.333V256z" />
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </svg>
                <span class="ml-1">6 mins ago</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rounded overflow-hidden border-4 border-red-400 shadow-lg">
        <a href="/room/{{room.id}}">
            <div class="relative">
                <img class="w-full"
                    src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/196667/pexels-photo-196667.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
                    alt="Sunset in the mountains">
                <div
                    class="hover:bg-transparent transition duration-300 absolute bottom-0 top-0 right-0 left-0 bg-gray-900 opacity-25">
                </div>
                <a href="#!">
                    <div
                        class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 bg-indigo-600 px-4 py-2 text-white text-sm hover:bg-white hover:text-indigo-600 transition duration-500 ease-in-out">
                        {{room.id}}
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="!#">
                    <div
                        class="text-sm absolute top-0 right-0 bg-indigo-600 px-4 text-white rounded-full h-16 w-16 flex flex-col items-center justify-center mt-3 mr-3 hover:bg-white hover:text-indigo-600 transition duration-500 ease-in-out">
                        <span class="font-bold">27</span>
                        <small>March</small>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class="px-6 py-4">
            <a href="#"
                class="font-semibold text-lg inline-block hover:text-indigo-600 transition duration-500 ease-in-out">{{room.name}}</a>
            <p class="text-gray-500 text-sm">
                {{room.desc}}
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="px-6 py-4 flex flex-row items-center">
            <span href="#" class="py-1 text-sm font-regular text-gray-900 mr-1 flex flex-row items-center">
                <svg height="13px" width="13px" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512"
                    style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
                    <g>
                        <g>
                            <path d="M256,0C114.837,0,0,114.837,0,256s114.837,256,256,256s256-114.837,256-256S397.163,0,256,0z M277.333,256
      c0,11.797-9.536,21.333-21.333,21.333h-85.333c-11.797,0-21.333-9.536-21.333-21.333s9.536-21.333,21.333-21.333h64v-128
      c0-11.797,9.536-21.333,21.333-21.333s21.333,9.536,21.333,21.333V256z" />
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </svg>
                <span class="ml-1">6 mins ago</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rounded overflow-hidden border-4 border-red-400 shadow-lg">
        <a href="/room/{{room.id}}">
            <div class="relative">
                <img class="w-full"
                    src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/196667/pexels-photo-196667.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
                    alt="Sunset in the mountains">
                <div
                    class="hover:bg-transparent transition duration-300 absolute bottom-0 top-0 right-0 left-0 bg-gray-900 opacity-25">
                </div>
                <a href="#!">
                    <div
                        class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 bg-indigo-600 px-4 py-2 text-white text-sm hover:bg-white hover:text-indigo-600 transition duration-500 ease-in-out">
                        {{room.id}}
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="!#">
                    <div
                        class="text-sm absolute top-0 right-0 bg-indigo-600 px-4 text-white rounded-full h-16 w-16 flex flex-col items-center justify-center mt-3 mr-3 hover:bg-white hover:text-indigo-600 transition duration-500 ease-in-out">
                        <span class="font-bold">27</span>
                        <small>March</small>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class="px-6 py-4">
            <a href="#"
                class="font-semibold text-lg inline-block hover:text-indigo-600 transition duration-500 ease-in-out">{{room.name}}</a>
            <p class="text-gray-500 text-sm">
                {{room.desc}}
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="px-6 py-4 flex flex-row items-center">
            <span href="#" class="py-1 text-sm font-regular text-gray-900 mr-1 flex flex-row items-center">
                <svg height="13px" width="13px" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512"
                    style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
                    <g>
                        <g>
                            <path d="M256,0C114.837,0,0,114.837,0,256s114.837,256,256,256s256-114.837,256-256S397.163,0,256,0z M277.333,256
      c0,11.797-9.536,21.333-21.333,21.333h-85.333c-11.797,0-21.333-9.536-21.333-21.333s9.536-21.333,21.333-21.333h64v-128
      c0-11.797,9.536-21.333,21.333-21.333s21.333,9.536,21.333,21.333V256z" />
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </svg>
                <span class="ml-1">6 mins ago</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem with the position where you put loop, change your code like this to make loop work inside the grid

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 border-4 border-red-400 lg:grid-cols-4 sm:grid-cols-2 gap-10">
{% for room in rooms %}
    <div class="rounded overflow-hidden border-4 border-red-400 shadow-lg">
        <a href="/room/{{room.id}}">
            <div class="relative">
                <img class="w-full"
                    src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/196667/pexels-photo-196667.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
                    alt="Sunset in the mountains">
                <div
                    class="hover:bg-transparent transition duration-300 absolute bottom-0 top-0 right-0 left-0 bg-gray-900 opacity-25">
                </div>
                <a href="#!">
                    <div
                        class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 bg-indigo-600 px-4 py-2 text-white text-sm hover:bg-white hover:text-indigo-600 transition duration-500 ease-in-out">
                        {{room.id}}
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="!#">
                    <div
                        class="text-sm absolute top-0 right-0 bg-indigo-600 px-4 text-white rounded-full h-16 w-16 flex flex-col items-center justify-center mt-3 mr-3 hover:bg-white hover:text-indigo-600 transition duration-500 ease-in-out">
                        <span class="font-bold">27</span>
                        <small>March</small>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class="px-6 py-4">
            <a href="#"
                class="font-semibold text-lg inline-block hover:text-indigo-600 transition duration-500 ease-in-out">{{room.name}}</a>
            <p class="text-gray-500 text-sm">
                {{room.desc}}
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="px-6 py-4 flex flex-row items-center">
            <span href="#" class="py-1 text-sm font-regular text-gray-900 mr-1 flex flex-row items-center">
                <svg height="13px" width="13px" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512"
                    style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
                    <g>
                        <g>
                            <path d="M256,0C114.837,0,0,114.837,0,256s114.837,256,256,256s256-114.837,256-256S397.163,0,256,0z M277.333,256
      c0,11.797-9.536,21.333-21.333,21.333h-85.333c-11.797,0-21.333-9.536-21.333-21.333s9.536-21.333,21.333-21.333h64v-128
      c0-11.797,9.536-21.333,21.333-21.333s21.333,9.536,21.333,21.333V256z" />
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </svg>
                <span class="ml-1">6 mins ago</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```